# Текущее значение переменной в консоли

Tags: javascript, переменные

Добрый день!

JS

```
 var clicks = 0;
    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вызвать в консоли текущее значение переменной (например, после 5 кликов). Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Выводим каждые 5 кликов...
Либо по аналогии вывести один раз 5.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clicks;
  if (clicks % 5 == 0) {
    console.log(clicks);
  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="onClick()">Click</button>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Александр, не за что:)